# CSS style for a Navbar

Tags: html, css

I have this Navbar and I and I want that when a anchor is clicked it get's underlined using CSS:

```
<div id="nav"> 
            <a data-field="home" class="nav-menu">Homepage</a> <span>|</span>
            <a data-field="about" class="nav-menu">About us</a> <span>|</span>
            <a data-field="support" class="nav-menu">Support</a> <span>|</span>
            <a data-field="contact" class="nav-menu">Contact</a>        
</div>
```

Also how can I make the same thing with a list:

```
<ul>
    <li><a data-field="home" id="homelink" class="tray-menu" id="tray-active" >Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a data-field="news" id="newslink" class="tray-menu">News</a></li> 
    <li><a data-field="products" id="productslink" class="tray-menu">Products</a></li>
    <li><a data-field="sales" id="saleslink" class="tray-menu">General Sales T&C</a></li>
    <li><a data-field="job" id="jobslink" class="tray-menu">Job Opportunities</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this case, this case how do I make a `<li>` element get a specific "selected" css style while the other `<li>` in the  gets grayed out or something?

In Javascript its easy, just manipulate the DOM and set the id or class tag.

**Update:**

Basically, I have this working, but with using Java (GWT); However I want to know if this is possible to do using just plain CSS and HTML

Comment: Give the `id` to the `<li>` element

Comment: What have you tried? you are saying you want this and that. let us know your efforts and we will help you ..

Comment: Are you looking for the `:active` pseudo selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this effect on the whole page use:

```
a:link 
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
a:visited 
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
a:hover 
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#008F68;
}
a:active 
{
text-decoration:underline;
color:#000;
}
```

Or for just the Navigation use the same but put 'li' in front of everything.

The 'Active' attribute' of the CSS is the one that is called upon click.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the :target pseudo selector might do the trick.  (*See http://css-tricks.com/on-target/ ) (Will not work in older versions of IE)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li id="homelink"><a href="#homelink" data-field="home" class="tray-menu" id="tray-active">Homepage</a>  </li>
  <li id="newslink"><a href="#newslink" data-field="news" class="tray-menu">News</a></li> 
  <li id="productslink"><a href="#productslink" data-field="products" class="tray-menu">Products</a></li>
  <li id="saleslink"><a href="#saleslink" data-field="sales" class="tray-menu" href="#saleslink">General Sales T&C</a></li>
  <li id="jobslink"><a href="#jobslink" data-field="job" class="tray-menu">Job Opportunities</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
:target {
text-decoration: underline;
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for "a"  links  (the below lines applies for all links in the page)

```
a:active 
{
text-decoration:underline;
color:red;
}
```

for second issue give a `classname` to ul like `myul`

```
<ul class="myul">


.myul li {
 background-color:red;
}
.myul li.selected {
 background-color:blue;
}
```